# Format Text File in python

Tags: python, regex, list

**Sample Text File:**

```
["abc","123","apple","red","<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"],

["abc","124","orange","blue","<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"],

["abc","125","almond","black","<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"],

["abc","126","mango","pink","<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
abc 123 apple red 'link1'>zzz

abc 124 orange blue 'link1'>zzz

abc 125 almond black 'link1'>zzz

abc 126 mango pink 'link1'>zzz
```

I just want the file to be free of braces, commas separated by white spaces, and obtain only the link of the last element in the line.

I tried using Lists in Python.

I dont know how to proceed. Guess, I am going wrong somewhere. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
import sys
import re

Lines = [Line.strip() for Line in open (sys.argv[1],'r').readlines()]



for EachLine in Lines:
    Parts = EachLine.split(",")
    for EachPart in Parts:

        EachPart = re.sub(r'[', '', EachPart)
        EachPart = re.sub(r']', '', EachPart)
```

Comment: Umm... you're not outputting anything at all yet? I think a `print ' '.join(Parts)` might feature in there?

Comment: I really don't think you'll need regex for this. you just need to parse the list as you normally do.

Comment: File "FormatToCsv.py", line 12
    EachPart = re.sub(r '[', '', EachPart)  This is the error that i am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using the following script:

```
import csv
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='"')
    for cols in csv_input:
        if cols:
            cols = [x for x in cols[1:-1:2]]
            link = re.search(r"('.*?)<", cols[-1])
            if link:
                cols[-1] = link.group(1)

            f_output.write('{}\n'.format(' '.join(cols)))
```

This will give you `output.txt` containing:

```
abc 123 apple red 'link1'>zzz
abc 124 orange blue 'link1'>zzz
abc 125 almond black 'link1'>zzz
abc 126 mango pink 'link1'>zzz
```

**Update** - There is a simplified version of this code running here on [repl.it](https://repl.it/BGbK) to show the correct output. Input comes from a string, and output is displayed. Just click the `Run` button.

**Update** - Updated to skip blank lines

Comment: Hi Martin, this looks good. But i am getting an error:: cols[-1] = re.search(r"'(.*?)'", cols[-1]).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

Comment: Do all of your input lines have a link?  I have updated it to cope with lines with no links which should fix your problem.

Comment: I am guessing you have a link which uses double quotes for the href? Can you check if this is the case?  The code works ok with your sample.

Comment: Yes Martin... you are correct. My href part appears like this: <a href='link1'>zzz</a> and i want output as 'link1'>zzz

Comment: Help would be appreciated if you could solve me with this??

Comment: I have updated the script and it appears to work with your new sample data.

Comment: no it doesn't. I hav updated the question. I dont think it gives the desired output. Your previous code was also the same

Comment: I am getting an output, but having an error as "link = re.search(r"('.*?)<", cols[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range" I think my file contains some blank columns in between or blank rows. Is it possible to negate this??

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to remove `[` and `]` with a regex, you need to escape the square brackets to match them as literal symbols. They are "special" regex characters denoting the character class boundaries and thus, need special treatment.

Here is a sample regex replacement:

```
EachPart = re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', EachPart)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/IiKF4K)

However, you can remove them with `str.replace(old, new[, max])` that does not require a regex:

```
EachPart = EachPart.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/0gMl4m)

Comment: Works fine.... Thanks a lot. But each part is outputed as a separate line. Is it possible to output all parts in a line as a separate line. Like elements in Line 1 to be in Line 1???

Comment: You mean to output the `EachPart` on one line in the console? Like [this](https://ideone.com/tRaY4F)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `regex to remove []`

**Code:**

```
import ast
with open("check.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        check=ast.literal_eval(line.strip().strip(","))        
        print " ".join(check)
```

**Output:**

```
abc 123 apple red <a href='link1'</a>
abc 124 orange blue <a href='link2'</a>
abc 125 almond black <a href='link3'</a>
abc 126 mango pink <a href='link4'</a>
```

But to get only the value of href I used `regex`

**Code1:**

```
import re
import ast
with open("check.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        check=ast.literal_eval(line.strip().strip(",")) 
        if re.search("'([^']*?)'",check[4]):
            check[4]=re.search("'([^']*?)'",check[4]).group(1)
        print " ".join(check)
```

**output:**

```
abc 123 apple red link1
abc 124 orange blue link2
abc 125 almond black link3
abc 126 mango pink link4
```

**As per you requirement**

```
 a="<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"
 print re.search("'([^<]*?)<",a).group(1)
```

**output:**

```
link1'>zzz
```

**Code2:**

```
import re
import ast
with open("check.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        check=ast.literal_eval(line.strip().strip(",")) 
        if re.search("'([^<]*?)<",a):
            check[4]=re.search("'([^<]*?)<",a).group(1)
        print " ".join(check)
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh, ast seems to be an awesome module. Is it possible to remove href from each line??? I just want links to appear

Comment: @blackfury are you running the code in `code1` and what output are you getting

Comment: Hi vignesh, sorry. Your code works fine. But <a href='link1'>zzz</a>; My link appears like this, and  i want everything between = and </a>. Sorry, but your code works great. Output should be : 'link1'>zzz              Thanks a lot man. Help would be appreciated if you could provide a soln for this ??? I will mark yours as the correct answer

Comment: yeah that works for the single line... but could you modify your previous code to incorporate this??

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is valid python data structures you can read it in using [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('''["abc","123","apple","red","<a href='link1'</a>"]''')
['abc', '123', 'apple', 'red', "<a href='link1'</a>"]
```

You can also slice the link out of the string by taking everything after the 9th character and up until the 5th to last:

```
>>> s = "<a href='link1'</a>"
>>> s[9:-5]
'link1'
```

Putting it together:

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as output:
    with open(filename) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            values = ast.literal_eval(line)
            values[4] = values[4][9:-5]
            output.write(' '.join(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line may be processed as follows:

```
>>>line = ["abc","123","apple","red","<a href='link1'>zzz</a>"]

>>>' '.join([k if 'href=' not in k else k[9:-4] for k in line])
"abc 123 apple red link1'>zzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets around the file's contents and you have a valid JSON object:

```
import json
with open(filename) as lines:
    output = json.loads("[" + lines.read() + "]")
```

Now you can process the lines, for example removing the anchor around the link:

```
import re
for line in output:
    line[4] = re.search(r"'([^']*)'", line[4]).group(1)
    print " ".join(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import ast
import io
import re
import traceback

input_str = """["abc","123","apple","red","<a href='link1'</a>"],

["abc","124","orange","blue","<a href='link2'</a>"],

["abc","125","almond","black","<a href='link3'</a>"],

["abc","126","mango","pink","<a href='link4'</a>"]"""

filelikeobj = io.StringIO(input_str)

for line in filelikeobj:
    line = line.strip().rstrip(",")
    if line:
        try:
            line_list = ast.literal_eval(line)
        except SyntaxError:
            traceback.print_exc()
            continue
        for li in line_list[:-1]:
            print(li, end=" ")

        s = re.search("href\s*=\s*['\"](.*)['\"]", line_list[-1], re.I)
        if s:
            print(s.group(1), end="")
        print()
```